# Retrieving Amazon SES Event Data - retrieve custom data from bounce event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When I get the bounce event in the SNS I want to retrieve extra data regarding this email. I only have the messageID.

Is there a way to add custom header to SendEmail API?

Is there another way to retrieve custom data of specific email? I dont want to write to DB because it causes me performance issues when writing to DB whenever I send an email. I send millions email per day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the [bounce object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html#bounce-object), you already have access to the *bounce type*, *bounce subtype*, *bounced recipients* and *timestamp* data.

However, if you need more fine-grained detailed monitoring for the bounce event using Amazon CloudWatch or Amazon Kinesis Firehose, you can apply one or more [message tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_MessageTag.html) (as an array) to the emails you send. See [Monitoring Using Event Publishing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-using-event-publishing.html).

Comment: I did set Tags in my email send but didn't get the tags back in the bounce event. Do you think of any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

You could set `Tags` within your `sendEmail` request.

In case of a `Bounce` you are getting the tags back

```
{
    "eventType": "Bounce",
    "bounce": {
        "bounceType": "Permanent",
        [...]
    },
    "mail": {
        [...]
        "tags": {
            "ExampleTagName": ["ExampleTagValue"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did set Tags in my email send but didn't get the tags back in the bounce event. Do you think of any reason why?